# The App icon has changed on fabric.io and I am unable to revert it back with original icon

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I releases my IOS app beta versions through fabric.ios and its provided sdk. I have two different apps and both are using fabric sdk to release the app. I am using Xcode 8 and fabric sdk(v2.5.2). Let me explain my problem in steps, refer below

1. I have released few beta versions for app A.
2. I have released few beta versions for app B which I had release few months back, and now no more releasing but its still available on fabric.io
3. Today I was in requirement to run and test the app B, and it was showing me provisioning profile errors, may be it expired.
4. To rush the work, I used the app id of my app A, and was able to build and run the app B. I know I can use wildcard provisioning profile or may be can create new certificates, but I did not, to just to rush my work.
5. I gave a quick run and test the issue on app B and stopped work on it.
6. I was running my app A normally and worked on it.
7. Evening time, when I was releasing my app A though fabric sdk, it was showing the app icon (in local installed sdk and on web app as well) of app B in throughout the process.
8. I tried many possible ways to revert back on app icon A, like clear the xcode cache, fabric sdk cache, retry of build and run the app, retry to configure the app, but nothing worked out. Finally I release my app with wrong icon.
9. But further app releases should be with original icon. I need any suggestions or help on this if someone else has face the same problem ever before.
10. The last option would be delete it from fabric sdk and create as a new app. I am not preferring to do it, because I would be loosing all the crash report and release details from it.

Suggestions and answer much appreciate.

Comment: Have the same issue, but with Android. Any luck on resolving this?

Comment: @hadez30 Start with Logout from Fabric on your local system then I deleted the Fabric Sdk from system and remove all the configuration of fabric (include its pod files) from my Xcode project.  Make sure to clear all cache of Xcode and Fabric.io as well. The I installed and configure everything as fresh on local. And then next release the Icon was updated and latest Icon